# How do I point to an unary operator function from transform algorithm parameter inside a function template class member?

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointers, member

I have class that looks like this:

```
class A
{
    public:
        class variables_map vm /*! A boost::program_options variable map containing all program_options in use. */;
        char sep_to_space(char c);
        template <typename T>
        void VectorFromOption(char * sOption, vector<T> & n);
};

char A::sep_to_space(char c){
  return c == ',' || c == '<' || c == '>' ? ' ' : c;
}

template <typename T>
void A::VectorFromOption(char * sOption, vector<T> & n)
    string s=A::vm[sOption].as<string>();
    transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), &A::sep_to_space );
    stringstream ss(s);
    copy(istream_iterator<T>(ss), istream_iterator<T>(), std::back_inserter(n));
}
```

These work fine outside the class, but I cannot find the correct way to pass `sep_to_space()` as `transform`'s 4th parameter in the context of their being class members. If I comment them out, everything else compiles and runs correctly.

The above `&A::sep_to_space` produces the enigmatic error:

`1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\algorithm(671) : error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments`

which is currently over my head, I'm afraid. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is `sep_to_space` even a (non-static) member of `A`? It doesn't access any members and obviously doesn't need to. Make it a free function or a static member and everything is fine.

To answer the general question, though, you need to *bind* the member to the object it's being called on.

One option is to use the `bind` function from C++11 or Boost:

```
#include <functional> // or <boost/bind.hpp>

using std::placeholders::_1; // placeholder for the first argument
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), std::bind(&A::sep_to_space, this, _1));
```

Or, if you already have C++11 available anyways, just use a lambda:

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
    [this](char c){
      return sep_to_space(c);
    });
```

Comment: I don't have C++ 11 support yet. I made `sep_to_space` a member because I couldn't find another way to keep it in scope after I moved `VectorFromOption` to the .h file.  Making `sep_to_space` a static member seems to be the best immediate solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
using std::placeholders::_1;
transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), std::bind( &A::sep_to_space, this, _1));
```

(or boost::bind)

Comment: As is, this doesn't work. You're missing the placeholder for the `char` argument.

Comment: Thanks, next time feel three to edit the answer instead of posting a comment.